# Does jQuery cancel remove() on an element if that element is being animate()ed?

Tags: jquery

I have this code here which is supposed to fadeOut / aminate to 0 width and then remove() some elements. But for some reason the remove() is not working.

```
$('#submitUsage').click(function(){
  var bahoooga = $('#inputUsage').val().replace(/\D/g,'');
  var bahoooga = bahoooga + " KWh";
  $(this).parent().parent().children('td:nth-child(2)').html(bahoooga);
  $('#editData td:last-child, #editData th:last-child').animate({
    width: '40px'
  }, 1500);
  $('#inputUsage').animate({
    width: '0px',
    opacity: '0'
  }, 1000);
  $('#cancelUsage, #submitUsage').fadeOut(1000);
  $('#inputUsage, #cancelUsage, #submitUsage').remove();
});
```

I had the remove() inside a setTimeout() function, which is what I want, but that wasn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to chain those like this:

```
$('#inputUsage').animate({
    width: '0px',
    opacity: '0'
}, 1000).promise().done(function(){
  $('#cancelUsage, #submitUsage').fadeOut(1000, function(){
     $('#inputUsage, #cancelUsage, #submitUsage').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: sweet, that's much cleaner than what i had

Answer (score 0):

You should remove only the element once the animation has finished. You can't do all of them and assume they finish at the same time EXACTLY (even tho they are both at 1000 ms).

```
target.fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).remove();});
```

For you it will look like:

```
$('#inputUsage').animate({
  width: '0px',
  opacity: '0'
  }, 1000).promise().done(function() { $(this).remove(); });

$('#cancelUsage, #submitUsage').fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```